# Generic activities for different objects

Tags: java, android, api, generics, android-activity

I'm currently building an app towards an API. Whenever I want to gather a list of objects from the API, the following lifecycle applies:

1. Start activity
2. Invoke GET request on BASE_URI/objects
3. Fill in the objects in a ListView

The activities are built up from the same components: ArrayAdapter, ProgressBar, an asynchronous task etc. The only things that may differ is the activity that gets called when I click on an object in the list, because the objects sometimes have different properties, I want to display them with a different style.

Now I'm wondering: Is it possible to make a generic activity repository? Such as...

```
public ActivityStore<T> extends ListActivity {
   ...
}
```

where I pass nothing but the API path and the reference type of the objects to deserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And who would call `ActivityStore<Dog>` ? Your manifest ?
No, you can't do just that.

But, if you got something like `DogStoreActivity extends ActivityStore<Dog>`, then it's perfectly fine to define Activities like this.

Comment: Not for the first activity, of course. And for some activities, I need concrete implementations to define the object type.

Comment: Ok, so if you got something like DogStoreActivity extends ActivityStore<Dog>, then it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep just one activity with list view and different adapters for different type of data.

Create one `AsyncTask` to get the data from server and set appropriate adapter to the `ListView`.

You can also create one base activity that all other activities extend and put your common code there.

Comment: `public class MyActivity { private Adapter1; private Adapter2; private Adapter3; private Adapter4; `... What a mess.